# X-axis labels are not properly displaying in d3

Tags: d3.js, svg

I am new in d3. I am trying correctly draw the x-axis label

The problem that i am facing is

if i use this command to draw x-axis

```
var xScale = scaleOrdinal().domain(extent(data, xValue))
  .range([0, innerWidth]);
```

The 'extent' function displays only the first and last value of the array along the x-axis. But I want to display all values in the array on the x-axis.

[image]

For resolving this issue i used array.map function

```
 var xScale = scaleOrdinal().domain(data.map(xValue))
  .range([0, innerWidth]);
```

but it is displaying labels one upon the other along the edges of x-axis.

[image]

Here is my complete code file

```
import {
  select,
  csv,
  scaleLinear,
  scaleTime,
  scaleOrdinal,
  extent,
  axisLeft,
  axisBottom,
  line,
  curveBasis,
  nest,
  schemeCategory10,
  timeFormat,
  descending
} from 'd3';

import { colorLegend } from './colorLegend';
const svg = select('svg');

const width = +svg.attr('width');
const height = +svg.attr('height');

const render = data => {
  const title='Profit Comparision by Segment by Region'
 // Region,Sub_Category,Profit
  const xValue = d => d.Sub_Category;
  const xAxisLabel="Sub-Category"

  const yValue = d => d.Profit;
  const circleRadius = 6;
  const yAxisLabel="Profit"
  var barPadding = 0.2;
  const colorValue = d => d.Region;

  const margin = { top: 60, right: 160, bottom: 88, left: 105 };
  const innerWidth = width - margin.left - margin.right;
  const innerHeight = height - margin.top - margin.bottom;

  /*const xScale = scaleLinear()
    .domain(extent(data, xValue))
    .range([0, innerWidth])
    .nice();*/
 var xScale = scaleOrdinal().domain(data.map(xValue))
  .range([0, innerWidth]);
 /* var xScale = scaleOrdinal().domain(extent(data, xValue))
  .range([0, innerWidth]);*/
  console.log(data.map(xValue))
  const yScale = scaleLinear()
    .domain(extent(data, yValue))
    .range([innerHeight, 0])
    .nice();

  const colorScale = scaleOrdinal(schemeCategory10);

  const g = svg.append('g')
    .attr('transform', `translate(${margin.left},${margin.top})`);

  const xAxis = axisBottom(xScale)
    .tickSize(-innerHeight)
    .tickPadding(15);

  const yAxis = axisLeft(yScale)
    .tickSize(-innerWidth)
    .tickPadding(10);

  const yAxisG = g.append('g').call(yAxis);
  yAxisG.selectAll('.domain').remove();

  yAxisG.append('text')
      .attr('class', 'axis-label')
      .attr('y', -60)
      .attr('x', -innerHeight / 2)
      .attr('fill', 'black')
      .attr('transform', `rotate(-90)`)
      .attr('text-anchor', 'middle')
      .text(yAxisLabel);

  const xAxisG = g.append('g').call(xAxis)
    .attr('transform', `translate(0,${innerHeight})`);

  xAxisG.select('.domain').remove();

  xAxisG.append('text')
      .attr('class', 'axis-label')
      .attr('y', 80)
      .attr('x', innerWidth / 2)
      .attr('fill', 'black')
      .text(xAxisLabel);

  const lineGenerator = line()
    .x(d => xScale(xValue(d)))
    .y(d => yScale(yValue(d)))
    .curve(curveBasis);

  const lastYValue = d =>
    yValue(d.values[d.values.length - 1]);

  const nested = nest()
    .key(colorValue)
    .entries(data)
    .sort((a, b) =>
      descending(lastYValue(a), lastYValue(b))
    );

  console.log(nested);

  colorScale.domain(nested.map(d => d.key));

  g.selectAll('.line-path').data(nested)
    .enter().append('path')
      .attr('class', 'line-path')
      .attr('d', d => lineGenerator(d.values))
      .attr('stroke', d => colorScale(d.key));

  g.append('text')
      .attr('class', 'title')
      .attr('y', -10)
      .text(title);

  svg.append('g')
    .attr('transform', `translate(820,121)`)
    .call(colorLegend, {
      colorScale,
      circleRadius: 10,
      spacing: 38,
      textOffset: 20
    });
};


csv('data4.csv')
  .then(data => {
    data.forEach(d => {
       // Region,Sub_Category,Profit
        d.Profit = +d.Profit;

    });
    render(data);
  });
```

How to display those labels along x-axis correctly?

Here is the link to my code on [vizhub](https://vizhub.com/princit/0dd32a40d74049ecb7befd7bdffc731c?edit=files&file=index.js)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Problem**

The issue is the scale you are using, d3.scaleOrdinal. To use this scale one generally has one discrete in the range for every discrete value in the domain:

> If range is specified, sets the range of the ordinal scale to the
>   specified array of values. The first element in the domain will be
>   mapped to the first element in range, the second domain value to the
>   second range value, and so on. If there are fewer elements in the
>   range than in the domain, the scale will reuse values from the start
>   of the range. ([docs](https://github.com/d3/d3-scale#ordinal_range))

When you have only two values in the domain, you get only two labels, and they're mapped to the the two values in the range.

When you have more than two values in the domain, the two values in the range are recycled, resulting in overlap.

**Solution**

Instead of `d3.scaleOrdinal`, there are other, d3 scales that can be used: `d3.scaleBand` or `d3.scalePoint`. While d3 scale ordinal is used to map ordinal domains to ordinal ranges, these other two can map ordinal domains to a continuous range extent. Which is what you are attempting to do.

Each take a range of two values, in your case, the range you currently are using `[0,width]`. And, you'll need to specify every input value for the domain, as you have above with `.map()`.

Since you appear to be using a line, I'd suggest `d3.scalePoint`, `d3.scaleBand` assumes that there is a width to every element (like for a bar chart). *d3.scaleBand will have `xScale(value)` return the left hand side of the band, while the width of the band will be `xScale.bandwidth()`, this isn't as useful for line or scatterplots as the point will be in the middle of the band, hence the use of `d3.scalePoint()`*.